# Cannot save loop data from api to json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

i have problem with my code, all i need is just to save results from looping api into json file using writeFileSync. Here's my code:

```
function processRarity(limit) {
    var resultJson = [];
    for (var i = limit; i < limit + 100; i++) {
      const everything = async () => {
        const response = await fetch(
          "https://api-v2-mainnet.paras.id/token/asac.near::" + i
        );
        var json = await response.json();
        return json;
      };
      everything().then((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        resultJson = res;
      });
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(`${basePath}/results.json`, JSON.stringify(resultJson, null, 2));
}
```

when i check my json file, all i get is just:

```
[]
```

Comment: You're not waiting for the async API calls to return before you write to the file.

Comment: so what should i do? @Barmar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `await` the calls to `everything()`.

Also, you should be pushing onto `resultJson`, not reassigning it each time through the loop.

```
const everything = async (i) => {
    const response = await fetch(
        "https://api-v2-mainnet.paras.id/token/asac.near::" + i
    );
    var json = await response.json();
    return json;
};


async function processRarity(limit) {
    var resultJson = [];
    for (var i = limit; i < limit + 100; i++) {
        let res = await everything(i);
        console.log(res);
        resultJson.push(res);
    }
    fs.writeFileSync(`${basePath}/results.json`, JSON.stringify(resultJson, null, 2));
}
```